# Correlated update gets "single-row subquery returns more than one row"

Tags: oracle, correlated-subquery

I am trying to update "my_value" column of table "my_table" based on "a_value" column in "result_table" table, using correlated update. When I run something similar to the following:

```
my_table:

OrderID  my_volume my_value  
----------------------------
1         100        NULL
2          50        NULL

result_table: 

OrderID  a_value   a_type  
----------------------------
1         2000      BUY
2         3500      SELL
```

My_table (after running UPDATE query) should become:

```
OrderID  my_volume my_value  
----------------------------
1         100        2000
2          50        3500
```

My Update statement:

```
update my_table set 
my_value=
(select a_value 
from result_table
join my_table on 
result_table.orderID = my_table.orderID )
where orderID in
(select my_table.orderID from my_table,result_table
where
result_table.orderID = my_table.orderID);
```

I get

> "single-row subquery returns more than one row" error.

How the query can be corrected so the `SELECT` statement return single row for each call?

Comment: Can you please post some sample data and desired result. Also is it possible that you have more than one row in `result_table` for a single value of `orderID`? Maybe you want to consider `MERGE`

Comment: As Aleksej says, there are seemingly two rows returned for you correlated subquery. What is the primary key of my_table  and is it a one to many relationship to result_table. You could always just add a `distinct` to your subquery and that would sort it.

Comment: @Aleksej: I have bow added some samples. I hope it helps. Though it is a simplified version of the query I am trying to run, but the idea is to copy one column from another table based on value of OrderID column.

Comment: Is it possible that you have an `orderId` in `my_table`  for which you have no rows in `result_table`? Or a value for which you have more than one row in `result_table`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best is to use `MERGE`:

```
Merge into my_table mytab
using result_table  rsltab
 on (mytab.id = rsltab.id)

When matched then
update
SET mytab.my_value = rsltab.a_value;
```

Answer (score 1):

just use as easy as this :

```
update my_table v set v.my_value = ( select a_value from result_table r where r.OrderID = v.OrderID );

select * from my_table;
ORDERID MY_VOLUME   MY_VALUE
------- ---------   --------
1          100        2000
2           50        3500
```

you already have unique `OrderID`s. So, there's no problem.

[D e m o](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/fa4f5/1)

Answer (score 1):

The `MERGE` solution is probably best, but just for the record your `UPDATE` had some extra joins in it that were probably the cause of the error. Assuming `result_table.orderid` is unique, it looks like all you needed was:

```
update my_table
set    my_column =
       ( select my_value
         from   result_table
         where  result_table.orderid = my_table.orderid )
where  orderid in
       ( select orderid
         from   result_table );
```

or if `result_table.orderid` has a unique constraint/index:

```
update ( select t.my_column, r.my_value
         from   my_table t
                join result_table r on r.orderid = t.orderid )
set my_column = my_value;
```